# Congruence Class of Negative Integers in a Multplicative Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

As part of a larger problem, I need to find the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^*$ generated but the congruence class of -1.  I understand that this is a multiplicative group with elements {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} where 1 is the identity, 3 and 5 are inverses, 2 and 4 are inverses and 6 is its own inverse.  I have found the subgroups to be {1, 6} and {1, 2, 4}.  However, I cannot figure out which positive integer is in the same congruence class as -1. I understand negative congruences classes in additive groups such as $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})$ but for whatever reason I cannot figure it out in terms of multiplicative groups and haven't found anything online.

Comment: In fact $\Bbb{Z}_7$ is a ring, so the congruence classes do not change when you consider multiplication rather than addition.

Comment: Is your algebra course groups-first or rings-first? Have you studied (quotient) rings yet?

Comment: It was groups first but we have studied rings as well.  The larger problem is determining the Galois correspondence of a given field extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each *elements* of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times$ is also an element of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ itself. When you go from the additive group to the multiplicative group, the *operation* changes, and some of the elements (such as $0$) disappear, but the elements that *remain* are the same objects as they were in the additive group.

So the element of $(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times$ that contains $-1$ is neither more nor less than the element of $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ that contains $-1$. And you know what that is, I hope?

Comment: It would be 1 since -1 =7(-1) + 1 mod 7, wouldn't it?  However, that would mean that the subgroup generated by the class would be either the trivial group or Z7 depending on whether you did it with multiplication or addition as the operation, but that doesn't seem to align with the rest of the problem.

Comment: @user1593858: No, $-1$ and $1$ are not in the same congruence class. $7(-1)+1$ is $-6$ which is certainly not congruent to $-1$. On the other hand $-1$ would be congruent to $-1+7$ ...

Comment: I see what I did wrong.  It should be 6 which would make it fit in much better with rest of the problem

Comment: @user1593858: Yes!